# Não consigo centrar o botão com o css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Não estou a conseguir centralizar o botão proceed to checkout.
Queria passar o paypal para o lado esquerdo.
Alguem me pode ajudar,estou a usar o wordpress.

http://ttu.awd.pt/carrinho/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa adicionar o seguinte css na sua folha de estilo:

```
.woocommerce #payment {
float: none !important;
width: 76% !important;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-row.place-order {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Não é a melhor solução, o ideal é você passar o seu código de css onde está tendo dificuldade para que possamos te ajudar melhor.